# Thousands of product Images that have different size and aspect ratio, how to make them fit

Tags: image, photoshop, aspect-ratio, bulk

So I just received a bulk of thousands of pictures from a client in order to add/assign them to some Virtuemart products.

The images I received have different aspect ratios. Some are portrait images, others are landscape, some are 1:1 and everything in between. If I import them like they are in Virtuemart, the looks of the product page will vary, which is something I don't want.

Currently, I am considering a couple of solutions. One could be to find a way to wrap them in a container and make them fill that container however they like using css, the other option, is to find a way to convert the images to a specific aspect ratio, let's say 4:3 and fill the empty pixels with white color, or something in those lines. There will be issues again, with inconsistent background colors, but I think that this is a tradeoff both me and my client have to accept.

Currently, I am investigating the second option, but I am unable to find a solution. I am not able to find a software or other method to achieve that.

MY OS is Windows 10
The image files are about 20000 files or something in those lines

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could write an action to make them all square if that would help? Record this process as an action:

```
Select All
Copy Merged
Deselect Layers
Paste in Place
Transform 90degrees
Reveal All
Delete Layer
Make Fill Layer (Solid white layer)
Send Current Layer to Back
```

This will give you a square image with a white background where the image is smaller than the frame.